# JSON Stringify Removing Data From Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on sending JSON, via jQuery ajax, to a Node server. My jQuery ajax is working. See below.

```
var user = JSON.stringify(userObject);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/save',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.link, 'here is the link');
        callback(data.link);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    });
```

My issue is that when I console log user, a json object that has been stringified, I have information inside arrays that are being lost. The part of the object I am losing looks like this.

[image: Losing this part]

And it is showing up stringified in the console like this:

[image: stringified console log]

The information that is stored inside of those arrays inside of the parent user object are not being stored. Any suggestion to why this might be will help. If you have any alternative methods that I can use to send this data structure via jQuery ajax, please let me know.

**Edit**
Here is where regions is created:

```
// Add regions to the bracket layout object
        user.regions = [];
        for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
            user.regions[a] = [];
            user.regions[a].columns = [];
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you `JSON.stringify` at first place?

Comment: This issue is not the console log. I am getting the data.link. Thanks is working. The issue is, that is information that is being stored in 'regions' is being lost when the object is stringified.

Comment: Your question does not have even a single word that explained what is `regions` and where it supposed to come from.

Comment: I have to stringify to send to the server. If I don't stringify it I get a 400 code. No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header... error

Comment: What is being sent and what is supposed to be returned. Confusing which end is your problem

Comment: Stringification has nothing to do with that error and it is not required to stringify. I would even say that stringification makes more harm than good

Comment: Regions is an array inside of the object. 0 and 1 are arrays inside of the regions array. The both contain more arrays and objects.

Comment: The console pic shows that both the Arrays are empty arrays, with zero elements.

Comment: none of this is making sense. Please update question with full details

Comment: You have two empty arrays in regions array. And what should they contain? Are you sure you haven't lost their contents before the request? Please check user object before sending ajax.

Comment: @BatScream you can see more of the object here http://cl.ly/image/0H1s1x3k0A2p

Comment: What is on the screenshot? How and where did you get it from?

Comment: I added an edit for where regions is created. That might help. @zerkms those screenshots are from my javascript console in Chrome

Comment: How exactly did you get that output? You may assume we see your screen or can read your mind, but not on Thursdays, sorry.

Comment: keep showing us regions...but data that is being sent is user ... I voted to close since you just aren't connecting any dots. Put a proper prblem description together

Comment: @zerkms I got that output by console logging users before it was stringified and then after it was.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin not possible it would show up in console as object after it is stringified...it would be a string

Comment: Please clean up the question from irrelevant information. If ajax call is irrelevant - please remove and put all `console.logs` + the corresponding screenshots. Or better a single screenshot for: `console.log` before, `console.log` after for the single contiguous call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're creating **AN ARRAY** then continue working with it as with an object.

Use

```
user.regions[a] = {};
```

instead.

What happens is that `JSON.stringify` sees there is an array, tries to iterate over its numeric indexes which it does not have so it results in an empty array.

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Le80jdsj/

Comment: I thought that might be the issue. Ok! Thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same issue of seemingly losing data with `JSON.stringify`. Although when I would `console.Log()` I'd see the data existing.

PSA Let's just all agree to remember to make sure synchronous logic isn't in async functions ‍♂️

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34662095)